# When specifying MainAxisAligment as key value in json i get null value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a use case where i need to specify the aligment of certain images with json object

This is the json object where i specify the aligment:

```
# json_object.json  

{
  "aligment" : "center"
}
```

I also have a method in another file where i grab this json object:

```
# get_json_object.dart

class GetJsonObject{
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getJson() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json_object.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }


}
```

I also have a another method where i do if else statement to specify which key ther is in key `aligment` from the json object. I first grab the mapped json from `GetJsonObject().getJson()` and then return the `MainAxisAlignment` based on the key value from key `alignment`.:

```
# get_alignment.dart

class GetAlignment {
   Future getAxisAlignment(String key) async {
    var mappedJson = await GetJsonObject().getJson();

    if (mappedJson[key] == mappedJson["start"]) {
      return MainAxisAlignment.start;
    } else if (mappedJson[key] == mappedJson["center"]) {
      return MainAxisAlignment.center;
    } else if (mappedJson[key] == mappedJson["end"]) {
      return MainAxisAlignment.end;
    }
  }
}
```

For the view i have stateful widget where i grab the return type `MainAxisAlignment` from `GetAlignment().getAxisAlignment()` from the file `get_alignment.dart` and use `setState` to set the return type from `GetAlignment().getAxisAlignment()` to the field `axisAlignment`. I then use field `axisAlignment` for the position of the `FlutterLogo()` with `Row()`:

```
# test_view.dart


class TestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestView> createState() => _TestViewState();
}

class _TestViewState extends State<TestView> {
  late MainAxisAlignment axisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start;


  setAlignment() async {
    final alignment =
    await GetAligmnent().getAlignment("alignment");

    setState(() {
      axisAlignment = alignment;
      
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    setAlignment();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: axisAlignment,
          children: [
            FlutterLogo()
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

But for some reason i get error in `setState()`: `E/flutter ( 9246): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'MainAxisAlignment'`

So the return type is `Null` value, but i don't understand why.

Comment: Your `Future getAxisAlignment` method doesn't handle the situation where all if statements fail, so you should return some default value if that happens.

Comment: Yes that is a good point

Answer (score 0):

I found out why i got `Null` as return type from `getAxisAlignment`. The reason for this was that i used wrong format inside the if else. I had to change `mappedJson["start"]` to just plain `String` like this:

```
  Future getAlignment(String key) async {
    var settings = await clientSettings;

    if (settings[key] == "start") {
      return MainAxisAlignment.start;
    } else if (settings[key] == "center") {
      return MainAxisAlignment.center;
    } else if (settings[key] == "end") {
      return MainAxisAlignment.end;
    } else {
      return MainAxisAlignment.center;
    }
  }
```

And i added default return type to get rid of the error when the return type was `Null`